# TimePicker не сохраняет значение

Tags: android, время

В своем приложении я использую `TimePicker`. Обнаружила, что если, выбирая время, не использовать кнопки "+", "-", а сразу набрать нужное количество часов или минут, то оно почти никогда не сохраняется. Например, если в часах я наберу 8, то это значение не сохранится. Если наберу 08, то сохранится. Если использую "+", "-", то все в порядке. Меня такая ситуация не устраивает. Может быть, кто-то подскажет как это исправить. Слушатель:

```
 picker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            Log.d("%%%%%%%%%%%%%", "new time: " + hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
        }
    });
```

не выводит сообщения, если я не использую кнопки  "+", "-", и выводит, если использую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогла команда `timePicker.clearFocus()` перед считыванием данных из `timepicker`. Ответ был [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992820/).