# Где найти исходники настроек даты и времени ОС Android

Tags: android, android-sources

В своем приложении использую `TimePicker` и он ведет себя не так, как ожидалось. В настройках даты и времени ОС `Android` тоже есть `TimePicker`, и он ведет себя образцово. 
 Хотелось бы посмотреть исходники настроек ОС. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти исходники ОС и как там найти нужный класс.

Comment: мне кажется, вы решаете проблему неправильным образом. Лучше объясните, как ведет себя ваш пикер, и как вы хотите, чтобы он себя вел.

Comment: @metalurgus Проблема описана в вопросе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512482/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из интернет-источников для изучения кода наиболее удобно пользоваться сервисом *GrepCode*, который помимо, собственно, исходников предоставляет линкованные ссылки для переходов по классам\методам, дерево структуры класса и прочие плюшки. Недостаток - отсутствие ресурсов.

[Исходники ОС Android на GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/) - здесь представлены исходные коды самой ОС. При клике на интересующую версию ОС в дереве структуры проекта можно докопаться до всех внутренностей. Можно так же через поиск найти конкретный класс, если точно знаете его имя.

[Исходники стандартных приложений на GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/) - здесь можно найти всякие календари, СМС-клиенты и прочие стоковые приложения ОС Android

Так же исходники представлены на git-сервере Google и на GitHub, для изучения кода они не очень удобны, так как это просто структурированные листинги (проект исходных кодов в чистом виде), зато они включают все ресурсы и прочие сопутствующие элементы, а не только код:

[Исходники Android на googlesource](https://android.googlesource.com/) - здесь представлен полный открытый исходный код ОС android и стоковых приложений, включая все ресурсы и тп.

То же самое [на Github](https://github.com/android)

Замечу сразу, что нельзя так просто взять, скачать эти исходники и засунуть в IDE, чтобы можно было комфортно пользоваться - проект имеет очень сложную структуру и связи, так что все будет полно ошибками.

Кроме того вы можете посмотреть все исходники и ресурсы ОС Android прямо в IDE, для той версии SDK, которая у вас установлена, если предварительно в SDK Manager скачаете раздел Source для этого SDK - это **самый удобный** вариант. Вы получаете и полную навигацию, все средства IDE и ресурсы.

SDK Manager:

[image: screen]

Android Studio:

[image: screen]

Comment: А как в IDE просматривать исходники, не зная названия класса? А ресурсы в исходниках SDK точно есть?

Comment: ресурсы - папка *res* на скриншоте из IDE / Если вы не знаете точно, что вам нужно ,то любой источник исходников вам будет полезен в равной мере. Ищите в дереве проекта, применяя логику, где бы могло быть то, что вам нужно, например, найти сначала приложение (скажем Настройки), где используется ввод даты, затем в нем класс, где эта дата вводится и так далее. Такого, что один раз ткнул мышкой и все получил здесь невозможно в принципе.  Так же можно пользоваться нечетким поиском (по общим словам, которые могли бы быть, используемым классам в искомом классе - `DatePicker` в вашем случае).

Comment: Я и не надеюсь на один клик. Дело в том, что исходники из SDK у меня на компе - это только файлы c расширение java, распределенные по папкам-пакетам. И это не проект Android-Studio, чтобы его просто можно было открыть в ней.  Как смотреть их в   IDE?

Comment: Если вы устанавливали исходники через SDK Manager, то они будут в IDE без всяких дополнительных действий, в отображении дерева классов - Project. Правда скорее всего исходников стоковых приложений в исходники SDK не включено.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Очень хороший ответ.  Я просто не видела его измененной версии.

Comment: Можно вас еще раз побеспокоить? В моем старом проекте был раздел External Libraries и внутри него раздел Android API 23 Platform. В моем же новом проекте этого раздела нет. Как его туда добавить. И влияет ли его наличие или отсутствие на размер apk-файла?

Comment: @iramm Смотрите скриншоты и пояснения в конце ответа. Чтобы получить исходники SDK их нужно сначала установить в SDK Manager (для каждого API отдельно), затем выбрать в AndroidStudio  отображение в дереве структуры проекта "Project" (по умолчанию отображение "Android" и там внешние библиотеки не отображаются). Наличие или отсутствие исходников SDK никаким образом не влияют на размер разрабатываемого приложения - они занимают место только на вашем компьютере и в сборку .apk, естественно, не включаются - на android-устройстве есть уже все необходимое изначально, на то оно и android-устройство :)

Comment: Вот этого-то Project вместо Android я и не заметила. Огромное вам спасибо. Теперь все ясно)))