# Помогите разобраться. Хочу просто посмотреть в online исходники Android OS, где это можно сделать?

Tags: android

Не хочу скачивать исходники Android, хочу просто, в режиме online, изучить их. Я смотрел в Google Git, github и даже какие-то старонние источники, но что-то не найду я репозитории с исходниками операционки Android. Там я видел отдельные приложения, ядро, но сами исходники... может это они и есть, но что-то сомнительно. Если всё же это они, помогите в них с ориентироваться пожайлуста)

Comment: Подозреваю, что это все же они и я бы сначала глянул на виртуальную машину dalvik (platform/dalvik) которая выполняет программы. А во вторую очередь глянул бы в ядро (platform/system/core).

Comment: если вам нужны исходники именно классов из API Android, то смотрите последний вариант из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512507/177345) - импорт исходников в IDE (к сожалению, GrepCode больше не работает). Например, исходники класса `Button` при этом будут по пути в дереве проекта: *External Libraries -> Android API .. -> Android.jar -> Android -> Widget-> Button*. Вид отображения дерева проекта при этом нужно перевести из режима Android в режим Project. Так же вам доступен поиск средствами IDE

Comment: Ну теперь понял, сейчас пойду разбираться с Git. Спасибо вам за отзыв

Comment: вам не нужен git, чтобы импортировать исходники Android в IDE - это делается через SDK Manager

Comment: Alex Krass, а Delvik или может быть ART? Или разницы нет?

Comment: Для обращения лучше пишите @ перед именем, чтобы приходило уведомление (пример @Алексей) . Вроде как разницы не должно быть, просто по разному компилируют программы при включении устройства. По идее delvik должен быть попроще, а art перспективнее на будущее. Но врать не буду, не могу дать обоснованный ответ на ваш вопрос.