# Возможно ли добавить в android studio вместо декомпилированных java классов настоящие исходники библиотек?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Я только начал изучать андроид разработку. И у меня возник вопрос: возможно ли добавить в android studio для стандартной библиотеки андроид, а также для подключаемых библиотек с открытым исходным кодом, вместо декомпилированных java классов, непосредственно исходники (kotlin/java), для того чтобы было удобно по ним шагать в дебагере?

Comment: насчет исходников фреймворка Android смотрите [последний абзац этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512507/177345) отображение дерева файлов проекта нужно поставить в Project (по умолчанию стоит Android)

Answer (score 3):

Когда переходите в какой-либо метод сторонней библиотеки, `idea` сначала декомпилирует файл `*.class`, а затем предлагает скачать её исходный код:

> **Download sources <kbd>>></kbd>**

[image: IDEA download sources screenshot]

---

Если вы сразу этого не сделали, то это можно сделать потом самому, а затем в настройках проекта указать расположение нужного файла:

> **Project structure <kbd>>></kbd> Libraries <kbd>>></kbd> Sources**

[image: IDEA project structure screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

**Настройки maven**:

Чтобы автоматически вместе с файлами библиотек скачивались также `sources` и `javadocs` откройте файл `~/.m2/settings.xml`, или создайте, если его там нет. Убедитесь, что в настройках `idea` используется это расположение (при желании можно задать своё).

```xml
<settings>

   <!-- ... другие настройки ... -->

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>downloadSources</id>
            <properties>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>downloadSources</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```