# Android Studio не признает класс из исходника TimePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня проблемы с работой `TimePicker` в моем приложении (проблема описана [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512482/)). Я его использую в `Preferences`. Поэтому мне нежелательно просто использовать `TimePickerDialog`, в котором этот самый `TimePicker` работает вполне хорошо.

Желая найти отличия в моем использовании этого виджета и в использовании его в `TimePickerDialog`, я открыла исходник этого класса в Android Studio. И тут оказалось, что интерфейс `android.widget.TimePicker.ValidationCallback` не распознается в Android Studio. Моя работа с `TimePicker` во всем совпадает, как мне кажется, с указанным образцом, кроме использования этого интерфейса. Но попробовать его использовать я не могу, так как Android Studio `"cannot resolve symbol ValidationCallback"` (и это при наличии импорта). Приложение не получится запустить на исполнение. Как мне быть?

### UPD:

Практическая ценность данного вопроса для меня резко понизилась, так как исходная проблема решилась (указанный интерфейс не понадобился). Теперь остался только теоретический интерес.

Comment: minSdk сколько стоит?

Comment: Я хочу от 10. Но не видит в 23.

Comment: Изменила minSDK на 23. По-прежнему не видит.

Comment: Создайте чистый проект и попробуйте импортировать android.widget.TimePicker. Проверьте работоспособность с нуля!